# Can't understand the error message from Clickhouse server

Tags: python, sockets, clickhouse

When I tried to connect to the Clickhouse server through python socket, I got the following message:

```
received data:  b'\x02e\x00\x00\x00\x10DB::NetException/DB::NetException: Unexpected packet from client\xf8\x070. Poco::Exception::Exception(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) @ 0x104191d0 in /usr/bin/clickhouse\n1. DB::Exception::Exception(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, int) @ 0x8fff8ad in /usr/bin/clickhouse\n2. ? @ 0x91083e1 in /usr/bin/clickhouse\n3. DB::TCPHandler::runImpl() @ 0x9105bd7 in /usr/bin/clickhouse\n4. DB::TCPHandler::run() @ 0x9107650 in /usr/bin/clickhouse\n5. Poco::Net::TCPServerConnection::start() @ 0x10304f4b in /usr/bin/clickhouse\n6. Poco::Net::TCPServerDispatcher::run() @ 0x103053db in /usr/bin/clickhouse\n7. Poco::PooledThread::run() @ 0x104b2fa6 in /usr/bin/clickhouse\n8. Poco::ThreadImpl::runnableEntry(void*) @ 0x104ae260 in /usr/bin/clickhouse\n9. start_thread @ 0x76db in /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so\n10. /build/glibc-OTsEL5/glibc-2.27/misc/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:97: __clone'
```

This is my python code

```
TCP_IP = "localhost"
TCP_PORT = 9000
BUFFER_SIZE = 1024
MESSAGE = "--user default --password xxxxxxx".encode("utf-8")
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
c = s.connect_ex((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
print (c)
s.send(MESSAGE)
data = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
s.close()
print ("received data: ", data)
```

I think the error comes from the wrong message sent to the server but it has no error when I typed in the same thing in the Ubuntu terminal. How do I fix it?

Comment: *clickhouse-client* is not command, try to pass valid command.

Comment: If I delete “clickhouse-client”, I still get the same thing

Answer (score 0):

It needs to follow the [ClickHouse Native Protocol Specification](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/tcp/) to get a valid response from the server.

Look at source code to get more details about the protocol:

- packet types - [Protocol.h](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/src/Core/Protocol.h)
- command implementations - [HELLO](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/0a453f5c8335d638ed1137794bdbae982e5a2823/src/Client/Connection.cpp#L142), [PING](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/0a453f5c8335d638ed1137794bdbae982e5a2823/src/Client/Connection.cpp#L292), etc.

---

For Python exist the package [clickhouse-driver](https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that support ClickHouse Native Protocol:

- packet types - [protocol.py](https://github.com/mymarilyn/clickhouse-driver/blob/master/clickhouse_driver/protocol.py)
- command implementations - [HELLO](https://github.com/mymarilyn/clickhouse-driver/blob/e27e21b175df38c2dd6cdb70dc94494cb9104397/clickhouse_driver/connection.py#L316), [PING](https://github.com/mymarilyn/clickhouse-driver/blob/e27e21b175df38c2dd6cdb70dc94494cb9104397/clickhouse_driver/connection.py#L376), etc.

---

I would recommend don't make the direct TCP-request but use [clickhouse-driver](https://clickhouse-driver.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)-package.